# Tough Algorithm - Do not let the same character repeat for n positions

Tags: java, algorithm

I wasn't able to figure this one out since I don't know how to calculate "inserting" an underscore.  I included my attempt at solving this problem.

> Given a string, do not let the same character repeat for n positions.  If it does repeat, insert an underscore to push
>   it X positions down.  The final output needed is just the total number of characters.
>
> - Example 1) Input "QQ",2 becomes "Q__Q", the return value is 4.
> - Example 2) Input "ABCA",2 becomes "ABCA" (no spaces needed), total characters is 4.
> - Example 3) Input "DEDEE", 1 becomes "DEDE_E", total chars is 6.
> - Example 4) Input "JKJK", 2 becomes "JK_JK", total characters is 5 (The toughest example).

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Spacer {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("QQ,2 = " + spacey("QQ", 2) + ", expected 4");
        System.out.println("ABCA,2 = " + spacey("ABCA",2) + ", expected 4");
        System.out.println("DEDEE,1 = " + spacey("DEDEE", 1) + ", expected 6");
        System.out.println("JKJK,2 = " + spacey("JKJK", 2) + ", expected 5");
    }

    private static int spacey(String word, int spaces) {
        // int shift = 0;
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            char letter = word.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(i + "=" + letter + " last saw " + hm.get(word.charAt(i)));
            if (hm.get(letter) == null) {
                hm.put(letter, i);
            } else {
                System.out.println(i + "-" + hm.get(letter) + "<=" + spaces);
                if (i - hm.get(word.charAt(i)) <= spaces) {
                    // System.out.println("add " + (spaces + 1 - (i - hm.get(letter))));
                    // shift += (spaces + 1) - (i - hm.get(letter));
                    word = word.substring(0, i) + "_" + word.substring(i);
                    System.out.println(i + " word=" + word);
                }
                hm.put(letter, i);      // update the hashmap with the last seen again
            }
        }
        return word.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: Why would **"DEDEE"** only be expected to have a length of **6** as in **"DEDE_E"** shown in your example? Why wouldn't it have an expectation of **8**? **"DE-DE--E"** (hyphen used here to indicate spaces).

Comment: JKJK", 2 becomes "JK_JK"? I think it becomes "JK__JK", 2 is the number of times _ is repeated, so in total 6 chars

Comment: I corrected the DEDEE example, it was only supposed to have an N=1.

Comment: JKJK only becomes JK_JK because there are 2 positions between the J's and the K's.  Thus satisfying the requirement.  This is the example that makes this so difficult.

Comment: N is the number of positions that each character should have between them.  X is potentially the inserted underscores to satisfy the distance of N between similar characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is (mainly) about inserting underscores. A key insight that can help move forward is that the input and output strings are different, so it would be cleaner to treat them as such, using a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for example. Additionally, it doesn't hurt at this stage to use temporary variables to capture concepts such as distance between characters. Leveraging these two ideas, you can have more self-explanatory code, for example:

```
public static String space(String input, int spaces) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for( char symbol : input.toCharArray() ) {
        int position = result.length();
        int lastPosition = map.getOrDefault(symbol, position-spaces-1);
        int distance = position - lastPosition -1;
        for( int j = 0; j < Math.max( spaces - distance, 0) ; j++ ) {
            result.append('_');
        }
        result.append(symbol);
        map.put(symbol, result.length()-1);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

(and once this is mastered and digested, it's of course possible to in-line the temps)

Comment: Indeed cleaner with StringBuilder! (+1)

Comment: I modified the code to just return result.length() and then it works!

Answer (score 1):

The requirement doesn't ask you to display the constructed string so we need to only do calculations. The regex (.+)\1 will match any repetition of 1 or more chars and countPattern returns how many times that pattern was found.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("QQ,2 = " + spacey("QQ", 2) + ", expected 4");
        System.out.println("ABCA,2 = " + spacey("ABCA",2) + ", expected 4");
        System.out.println("DEDEE,1 = " + spacey("DEDEE", 1) + ", expected 6");
        System.out.println("JKJK,2 = " + spacey("JKJK", 2) + ", expected 6");   //in becomes JK__JK, ie. 4 + 2x'_'
    }

    private static int spacey(String word, int spaces) {
        if(spaces<0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("should be positive value");
        }
        if(word==null){
            return 0;
        }
        if(spaces==0){
            return word.length();
        }
        final Pattern repeatedCharRegex = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\1");
        final int repetitions = countPattern(word, repeatedCharRegex);
        return word.length() + repetitions*spaces;
    }

    public static int countPattern(String references, Pattern referencePattern) {
        Matcher matcher = referencePattern.matcher(references);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()){
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an error in one of your test cases. Assuming you want to reproduce the cases in the quoted challenge, you need a 1 as second argument to the call to `spacey` here:

```
    System.out.println("DEDEE,1 = " + spacey("DEDEE", 1) + ", expected 6");
    //                        ^                       ^
```

The formula to calculate the number of underscores to insert is:

```
    previousindex + n + 1 - i
```

...where *previousindex* is the index at which the current letter occurred before, and *i* is the current index.

You can repeat an underscore with the `.repeat` string method. Don't forget to update *i* afterwards, so it keeps pointing to the currently processed character (which moved forward).

So your code could work like this:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Spacer {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("QQ,2 = " + spacey("QQ", 2) + ", expected 4");
        System.out.println("ABCA,2 = " + spacey("ABCA",2) + ", expected 4");
        System.out.println("DEDEE,1 = " + spacey("DEDEE", 1) + ", expected 6");
        System.out.println("JKJK,2 = " + spacey("JKJK", 2) + ", expected 5");
    }

    private static int spacey(String word, int spaces) {
        HashMap<Character, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0; i<word.length(); i++) {
            char letter = word.charAt(i);
            if (hm.get(letter) == null) {
                hm.put(letter, i);
            } else {
                int underscores = hm.get(letter) + spaces + 1 - i;
                if (underscores > 0) { // Need to add underscores
                    word = word.substring(0, i) + "_".repeat(underscores) + word.substring(i);
                    i += underscores; // update i so it still points to the current character
                }
                hm.put(letter, i);
            }
        }
        return word.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: **Note:** you need Java 11+ to utilize the [String#repeat()](https://howtodoinjava.com/java11/repeat-string-n-times/) method.